# How do I draw an arrow in my HTML comment?

Tags: html

I'm trying to write a comment in html that looks exactly like this :

"ClO2 + H2O --> ClH2O3"

So my code looks like this :

`<html>
....html code....
<!-- ClO2 + H2O --> ClH2O3 -->
....html code....
</html>`

But the comment is ending itself early. How do I fix this?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319809/escaping-html-inside-comment-tags

Comment: You can't put the "--" in an HTML comment as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a comment in HTML:

> 8.1.6 Comments
>
> Comments must start with the four character sequence U+003C LESS-THAN
>   SIGN, U+0021 EXCLAMATION MARK, U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, U+002D
>   HYPHEN-MINUS (" (U+003E) character, nor start with a U+002D
>   HYPHEN-MINUS character (-) followed by a ">" (U+003E) character, nor
>   contain two consecutive U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS characters (--), nor end
>   with a U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character (-). Finally, the comment must be
>   ended by the three character sequence U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, U+002D
>   HYPHEN-MINUS, U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN (-->).

You can't include `--` inside a comment, but you *can* use a nearly identical character in its place.

- `<!-- ClO2 + H2O ‑‑> ClH2O3 -->`  (Non-breaking hyphens, U+2011)
- `<!-- ClO2 + H2O ‒‒> ClH2O3 -->`  (Figure dashes, U+2012)
- `<!-- ClO2 + H2O ——> ClH2O3 -->`   (Em dashes, U+2014)

(I use two em-dashes here, since in a monospaced font it isn't really any longer than the other characters, although it should be.)

But as long as we are digging into Unicode, we might as well use an actual arrow:

```
<!-- ClO2 + H2O ⟶ ClH2O3 -->  (Long rightwards arrow, U+27f6)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to do this since it is interpreted by the web browser. I would suggest using a different set of characters to represent the arrow, like `->`, `==>` or something similar.